# Azure IoT Hub TLS certificate revocation

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

The IEC 62443-4-2 component requirement CR 1.9 "Strength of public key-based authentication" states:

> For components that utilize public-key-based authentication, those
> components shall provide directly or integrate into a system that
> provides the capability within the same IACS environment to:
> …
> c) validate certificates by checking a given certificate’s revocation
> status;

Which approach is used for certificate revocation for the TLS-encrypted communication with Azure IoT Hub: Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP) and/or Certificate Revocation Lists (CRLs)?

Is certificate revocation validation supported in the Azure IoT SDKs?

Answer (score 0):

IoT Hub does not perform certificate revocation checks as of now. You need to explicitly disable devices to prevent them from connecting.

Comment: If a server certificate of an IoT Hub instance cannot be revoked, then this is a potential threat for the instances themselves.

Comment: IoT Hub server certificate can of course be revoked by Microsoft, why shouldn’t it be possible…? 
IoT hub will not check if a DEVICE certificate has been revoked. To account for this you need to also disable a device in IoT Hub (along with revoking device certificate).

Comment: If you refer to YOUR CA cert in IoT Hub, you can revoke it but will also need to disable all devices which chain up to it. I’d suggest using DPS. It also does not check for cert revocation BUT you’ll have easier life disabling devices at scale using enrollment groups.

Comment: Thank you. So, the server certificate of the (own) IoT hub instance can be revoked.

Is the certificate revocation state validated in the Azure IoT SDKs?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you can control it. In C# SDK for AMQP: AmqpTransportSettings.CertificateRevocationCheck https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/master/iothub/device/src/AmqpTransportSettings.cs#L34
For MQTT: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/master/iothub/device/src/Transport/Mqtt/MqttTransportSettings.cs#L83

then e.g.
var settings = new AmqpTransportSettings(TransportType.Amqp)
            { CertificateRevocationCheck = true };
            
var deviceClient = deviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, new[] { settings });